# Can't use WebCam and Internal Microphone on Ubuntu Studio 20.04

Tags: sound, webcam

I have problem when try to connect to my webcam and microphone on Ubuntu Studio.. Here is my data from searching the web in 3 days and tried a lot of different things.

THe problem is:
Ater restart I can use Messenger to talk to mobile phone and both camera and microphone is perfect.But when connection to other PC's (Linux Mint and Windows 10) the camera is almost black and they can hear my voice but I can't hear them..

Below is a long list of my hardware...
I need help to learn how to enable camera and microphone on a acer aspire

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal


 Audio:     Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI                                                       
           driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 03:00.1 chip ID: 1002:15de                                                                                                  
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI driver: snd_hda_intel                                                      
           v: kernel bus ID: 03:00.6 chip ID: 1022:15e3                                                                                                                        
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-64-lowlatency            

ile Edit Options Buffers Tools Help                                                                                                                                           
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0408 Product=a031 Version=0006                                                                                                                              
N: Name="VGA WebCam: VGA WebCam"                                                                                                                                               
P: Phys=usb-0000:03:00.4-1/button                                                                                                                                              
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.4/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input20                                                                                          
U: Uniq=                                                                                                                                                                       
H: Handlers=kbd event16                                                                                                                                                        
B: PROP=0                                                                                                                                                                      
B: EV=3                                                                                                                                                                        
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                               
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000                                                                                                                              
N: Name="HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone"                                                                                                                                     
P: Phys=ALSA                                                                                                                                                                   
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.6/sound/card1/input21                                                                                                     
U: Uniq=                                                                                                                                                                       
H: Handlers=event17                                                                                                                                                            
B: PROP=0                                                                                                                                                                      
B: EV=21                                                                                                                                                                       
B: SW=4 
                                                                                                                                          
journalctl -k | grep -Ei "sound|audio|video"                                                                                                                                   
jan. 22 14:57:14 karlarne-Aspire kernel: ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)                                                                                                    
jan. 22 14:57:14 karlarne-Aspire kernel: ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)                                                                                          
jan. 22 14:57:14 karlarne-Aspire kernel: ACPI: Video Device [VGA2] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)                                                                        
jan. 22 14:57:14 karlarne-Aspire kernel: input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:0d/LNXVIDEO:02/input/input5                                    
jan. 22 14:57:14 karlarne-Aspire kernel: Modules linked in: video i2c_hid(+) wmi hid                                                                                           
jan. 22 14:57:14 karlarne-Aspire kernel: videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00                                                                                        
jan. 22 14:57:15 karlarne-Aspire kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client                                                                        
jan. 22 14:57:15 karlarne-Aspire kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:03:00.1: bound 0000:03:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])                                      
jan. 22 14:57:15 karlarne-Aspire kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.1/sound/card0/input19                            
jan. 22 14:57:15 karlarne-Aspire kernel: uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device VGA WebCam (0408:a031)                                                                                
jan. 22 14:57:15 karlarne-Aspire kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo                                                                                     
jan. 22 14:57:15 karlarne-Aspire kernel: USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)                                                                                                        
jan. 22 14:57:15 karlarne-Aspire kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC255: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker                             
jan. 22 14:57:15 karlarne-Aspire kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)                                                            
jan. 22 14:57:15 karlarne-Aspire kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)                                                                
jan. 22 14:57:15 karlarne-Aspire kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0                                                                              
jan. 22 14:57:15 karlarne-Aspire kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:                                                                                         
jan. 22 14:57:15 karlarne-Aspire kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Headset Mic=0x19                                                                              
jan. 22 14:57:15 karlarne-Aspire kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Internal Mic=0x12                                                                             
jan. 22 14:57:15 karlarne-Aspire kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.6/sound/card1/input21
```

Thanks a lot!
Karl